# How to tag IPTABLES rules?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, netfilter

I am going to use `iptables` for port forwarding to listen on requests from my LAN on port 8080 and answer with container at port 80, like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.15 --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to 10.0.3.103:80
```

I am not sure if the rule is right (feel free to correct it), but the question is:

- How to annotate this rule so that I can easily find and purge it?
- If `iptables` cannot do this, what can?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a *comment* module for iptables which should do what you need.  When adding a rule, one can add a comment like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow incoming ICMP"
```

Comment: Awesome. It is missing from `man iptables` on my system. Now I can see the comment in `iptables --list`.

Comment: @techtonik Have a look at `man 8 iptables-extensions` for a full list of what one can do with iptables.  Happy hacking!