# Find my rules in iptables

Tags: iptables

The `iptables` rules can be [annotated with comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245151/firewall-that-allows-to-tag-or-comment-rules-for-easy-filtering/245239#245239). How to select and remove rules using these comments?

Maybe there is another solution to tag rules and remove them based on that tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use fallowing command to list all rule in a file.

> iptables-save >abc.txt

Now you can edit abc.txt file as you want.
Then restore with below command

> iptables-restore < abc.txt

Comment: This is not atomic. Is this the only way? And how do I understand where one rule ends and another one starts?

Comment: Every  rule will be in a new line and it must be start with -I or -A or something like that. If you wanna remove any rule just remove that line.

Comment: Looks like rewriting `-A PREROUTING` to `-D PREROUTING` and reexecuting the rule from command line can make removal atomic.